# getting started

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, channel-api, webrtc, videochat

I want to create an app like https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=04188292. I know a little bit about webrtc but cannot get a hold of google app-engine.How to set it up for javascript and start coding??I tried this but it did not work

```
<script src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
//for inclusion of channel api
...
console.log(create_channel(1));
//gave an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: create_channel is not defined
```

Any tutorial/help would be appreciated
Is there any other way of using channel api?

Answer (score 1):

Why not you use [PUBNUB](http://www.pubnub.com/)?

I used [PUBNUB](http://www.pubnub.com/) for [this JavaScript ONLY WebRTC Experiment](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/javascript/). See [Source code](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/JavaScript-Only)!

Comment: how did you go about it? i mean where did you start?are there any tutorials on it?

Comment: If oou asking for PUBNUB --- then 1) http://www.pubnub.com/account-javascript-api-include and 2) http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/javascript-push-api --- if you asking for WebRTC .... I learnt by experiments....however it is true that I read all IETF RTCWeb specific drafts and I got the main idea from those docs...I learnt How to order WebRTC code by reading those drafts...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials out there. If you're working on the .NET stack, you might take a look at the sample that the XSockets guys put together:

http://xsocketswebrtc.codeplex.com/

It's a bit dated now, as it hasn't been updated to use the latest version of XSockets or of the WebRTC spec. I forked it to fix those issues, and ported the JS portion over to TypeScript while I was at it:

https://bitbucket.org/smithkl42/xsockets.webrtc/overview

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

The Channel API is only available on Google App Engine applications. It's unlikely you'll be able to use it for media transfer as the max message size is 32k.

The required Javascript is served from the application, once correctly configured.

Comment: For PubNub, I splitted SDP message into two parts....you can use tricks!! - https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Great work Ken on moving the "old" webRTC experiment!    We, Team XSockets.NET are going to release a new version soon , where we embed a set of nice WebRTC things, an easy to use JsApi for WebRTC purposes,

We just recently released a demo,based on fragment of that,

http://browsermeeting.com

At http://xsockets.net you will find more information very soon!